# AngularJS form validation using JSON Schema dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to validate json in AngularJS dynamically.
I am facing a problem loading fields from the schema to the page.
I am new to AngularJS so I don't have that much knowledge of it.
I created the form, but I cannot validate it dynamically.

```
    myApp.controller('appController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
        var NUMBER_REGEXP = /^[0-9]+$/;

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'JsonSchema.json' })
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.data = angular.fromJson(response);
                $scope.data = $scope.data.data;
                console.log($scope.data);
            });

        $scope.greeting = 'success!';

        $scope.handleErrors = function (data) {
            if(data !== undefined && data !== null) {
                angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
                    var form = value.form.field;
                    var fields = value.fields.field;
                    var error = form.errors;

                    if(form.compulsory) {
                        $scope.pageError = form.errors.compulsory;
                    }
                    else if(!(NUMBER_REGEXP.test(filds.field))) {
                        $scope.pageError = error.regex;
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.pageError = "An unexpected error has occurred, please try again later!";
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plunker usually helps with this type of problem, but ultimately it depends on which library you are using for working with JSON Schema to do the validation?

I work with [AngularJS Schema Form](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form) so once the JSON Schema is loaded you set it on the scope to the value assigned to the form to be providing the schema. This will then validate the form for you or await a user input before validating.

There are dozens of libraries that can handle validation of data independent of the form, the most popular for pure validation being [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) currently however [djv](https://github.com/korzio/djv) also looks promising.